# How to get any browser to print the header of a CSS `display: table` on every page the table spans?

Tags: css, browser, printing, html-table

Chrome, Edge and maybe more browsers ignore the per `display: table-header-group;` defined table header, so that the header is not repeated at pages the table spreads.

### Is there a trick to make every browser repeat the table header on the pages the table spans?

Attention: Java Script cannot be used. There is more to the site than just this one table. Therefore the header may not be printed on every page. Therefore `position: fixed` is not a solution.

## Example to demonstrate the problem

This is a responsive table. Firefox is printing the header at each page the table spans. Chrome and Edge unfortunately not.

```
<!--
    How to automatically print the headerer of a responsive CSS grid table that is implemented using display: grid on every printed page over which the table extends?
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>

<header>
    <title>CSS Display Table</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <style>
        @media print {
            @page {
                size: A4 portrait;
                margin: 40mm;
            }
        }

        /*
            A simple and airy grid table so that it spans several pages of paper despite having few lines.
        */

        #tableItems {
            display: table;
            /* remove bullets and other <ul> Unordered List properties */
            list-style-type: none;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: 12mm;
            padding: 0mm;
        }

        #tableItems .body {
            display: table-row;
        }

        #tableItems .headFull {
            display: table-header-group;
        }

        #tableItems .headReduced {
            display: none;
        }

        #tableItems li {
            display: table-cell;
            border: thin solid brown;
            padding: 2mm;
        }

        #tableItems .headFull li {

            vertical-align: middle;
            color: blue;
            background-color: cadetblue;
        }

        #tableItems .posAmountName,
        #tableItems .prices {
            /* like the row divs are not there */
            display: contents;
        }



        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

            #tableItems .headFull {
                display: none;
            }

            #tableItems .headReduced {
                display: table-header-group;
            }

            #tableItems .headReduced li {
                background-color: aquamarine;
                white-space: wrap;
            }

            #tableItems .posAmountName,
            #tableItems .prices {
                display: table-cell;
                border: thin solid red;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }

            #tableItems .posAmountName li,
            #tableItems .prices li {
                display: block;
                border: none;
                line-height: 20%;
            }

            #tableItems .name {
                margin-bottom: 2mm;
            }

            #tableItems .pos::before {
                content: "Pos";
            }

            #tableItems .pos::after {
                content: ":";
            }

            #tableItems .priceSingle::before {
                content: "Single =";
            }

            #tableItems .priceTotal::before {
                content: "Total =";
            }
        }
    </style>
</header>

<body>

    <!-- Test table to demonstrate reactiveness  -->
    <ul id="tableItems">

        <!-- Table header for high resolution -->
        <div class="headFull">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">
                    Position
                </li>
                <li class="amount">
                    Amount
                </li>
                <li class="name">
                    Product-Name
                </li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Product Description
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">
                    Price per Piece
                </li>
                <li class="priceTotal">
                    Price Total
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Table header for low resolution -->
        <div class="headReduced">
            <li class="posAmountName">
                Pos / Amount / Product
            </li>
            <li class="description">
                Description
            </li>
            <li class="prices">
                Price
            </li>
        </div>


        <!-- Table data -->
        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">001</li>
                <li class="amount">3 Pieces</li>
                <li class="name">DIGISOL</li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Solar heater controller with digital display.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">443,53 €</li>
                <li class="priceTotal">1.330,59 €</li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">
                    002
                </li>
                <li class="amount">
                    8 Pieces
                </li>
                <li class="name">
                    NIVA
                </li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Liquid level controller for skimmer pools.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">
                    415,34 €
                </li>
                <li class="priceTotal">
                    3.322,72 €
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">
                    003
                </li>
                <li class="amount">
                    3 Pieces
                </li>
                <li class="name">
                    ALLPOOL
                </li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Multifunctional pool controller.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">
                    2.276,08 €
                </li>
                <li class="priceTotal">
                    6.828,24 €
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Table dummy data for testing printing -->
        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">001</li>
                <li class="amount">3 Pieces</li>
                <li class="name">DIGISOL</li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Solar heater controller with digital display.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">443,53 €</li>
                <li class="priceTotal">1.330,59 €</li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">
                    002
                </li>
                <li class="amount">
                    8 Pieces
                </li>
                <li class="name">
                    NIVA
                </li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Liquid level controller for skimmer pools.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">
                    415,34 €
                </li>
                <li class="priceTotal">
                    3.322,72 €
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">
                    003
                </li>
                <li class="amount">
                    3 Pieces
                </li>
                <li class="name">
                    ALLPOOL
                </li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Multifunctional pool controller.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">
                    2.276,08 €
                </li>
                <li class="priceTotal">
                    6.828,24 €
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Table dummy data for testing printing -->
        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">001</li>
                <li class="amount">3 Pieces</li>
                <li class="name">DIGISOL</li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Solar heater controller with digital display.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">443,53 €</li>
                <li class="priceTotal">1.330,59 €</li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">
                    002
                </li>
                <li class="amount">
                    8 Pieces
                </li>
                <li class="name">
                    NIVA
                </li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Liquid level controller for skimmer pools.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">
                    415,34 €
                </li>
                <li class="priceTotal">
                    3.322,72 €
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">
                    003
                </li>
                <li class="amount">
                    3 Pieces
                </li>
                <li class="name">
                    ALLPOOL
                </li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Multifunctional pool controller.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">
                    2.276,08 €
                </li>
                <li class="priceTotal">
                    6.828,24 €
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Table dummy data for testing printing -->
        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">001</li>
                <li class="amount">3 Pieces</li>
                <li class="name">DIGISOL</li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Solar heater controller with digital display.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">443,53 €</li>
                <li class="priceTotal">1.330,59 €</li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">
                    002
                </li>
                <li class="amount">
                    8 Pieces
                </li>
                <li class="name">
                    NIVA
                </li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Liquid level controller for skimmer pools.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">
                    415,34 €
                </li>
                <li class="priceTotal">
                    3.322,72 €
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">
                    003
                </li>
                <li class="amount">
                    3 Pieces
                </li>
                <li class="name">
                    ALLPOOL
                </li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Multifunctional pool controller.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">
                    2.276,08 €
                </li>
                <li class="priceTotal">
                    6.828,24 €
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Table dummy data for testing printing -->
        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">001</li>
                <li class="amount">3 Pieces</li>
                <li class="name">DIGISOL</li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Solar heater controller with digital display.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">443,53 €</li>
                <li class="priceTotal">1.330,59 €</li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">
                    002
                </li>
                <li class="amount">
                    8 Pieces
                </li>
                <li class="name">
                    NIVA
                </li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Liquid level controller for skimmer pools.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">
                    415,34 €
                </li>
                <li class="priceTotal">
                    3.322,72 €
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">
                    003
                </li>
                <li class="amount">
                    3 Pieces
                </li>
                <li class="name">
                    ALLPOOL
                </li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Multifunctional pool controller.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">
                    2.276,08 €
                </li>
                <li class="priceTotal">
                    6.828,24 €
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Table dummy data for testing printing -->
        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">001</li>
                <li class="amount">3 Pieces</li>
                <li class="name">DIGISOL</li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Solar heater controller with digital display.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">443,53 €</li>
                <li class="priceTotal">1.330,59 €</li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">
                    002
                </li>
                <li class="amount">
                    8 Pieces
                </li>
                <li class="name">
                    NIVA
                </li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Liquid level controller for skimmer pools.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">
                    415,34 €
                </li>
                <li class="priceTotal">
                    3.322,72 €
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">
                    003
                </li>
                <li class="amount">
                    3 Pieces
                </li>
                <li class="name">
                    ALLPOOL
                </li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Multifunctional pool controller.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">
                    2.276,08 €
                </li>
                <li class="priceTotal">
                    6.828,24 €
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Table dummy data for testing printing -->
        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">001</li>
                <li class="amount">3 Pieces</li>
                <li class="name">DIGISOL</li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Solar heater controller with digital display.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">443,53 €</li>
                <li class="priceTotal">1.330,59 €</li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">
                    002
                </li>
                <li class="amount">
                    8 Pieces
                </li>
                <li class="name">
                    NIVA
                </li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Liquid level controller for skimmer pools.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">
                    415,34 €
                </li>
                <li class="priceTotal">
                    3.322,72 €
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">
                    003
                </li>
                <li class="amount">
                    3 Pieces
                </li>
                <li class="name">
                    ALLPOOL
                </li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Multifunctional pool controller.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">
                    2.276,08 €
                </li>
                <li class="priceTotal">
                    6.828,24 €
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Table dummy data for testing printing -->
        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">001</li>
                <li class="amount">3 Pieces</li>
                <li class="name">DIGISOL</li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Solar heater controller with digital display.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">443,53 €</li>
                <li class="priceTotal">1.330,59 €</li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">
                    002
                </li>
                <li class="amount">
                    8 Pieces
                </li>
                <li class="name">
                    NIVA
                </li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Liquid level controller for skimmer pools.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">
                    415,34 €
                </li>
                <li class="priceTotal">
                    3.322,72 €
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">
                    003
                </li>
                <li class="amount">
                    3 Pieces
                </li>
                <li class="name">
                    ALLPOOL
                </li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Multifunctional pool controller.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">
                    2.276,08 €
                </li>
                <li class="priceTotal">
                    6.828,24 €
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Table dummy data for testing printing -->
        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">001</li>
                <li class="amount">3 Pieces</li>
                <li class="name">DIGISOL</li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Solar heater controller with digital display.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">443,53 €</li>
                <li class="priceTotal">1.330,59 €</li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">
                    002
                </li>
                <li class="amount">
                    8 Pieces
                </li>
                <li class="name">
                    NIVA
                </li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Liquid level controller for skimmer pools.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">
                    415,34 €
                </li>
                <li class="priceTotal">
                    3.322,72 €
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">
                    003
                </li>
                <li class="amount">
                    3 Pieces
                </li>
                <li class="name">
                    ALLPOOL
                </li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Multifunctional pool controller.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">
                    2.276,08 €
                </li>
                <li class="priceTotal">
                    6.828,24 €
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Table dummy data for testing printing -->
        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">001</li>
                <li class="amount">3 Pieces</li>
                <li class="name">DIGISOL</li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Solar heater controller with digital display.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">443,53 €</li>
                <li class="priceTotal">1.330,59 €</li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">
                    002
                </li>
                <li class="amount">
                    8 Pieces
                </li>
                <li class="name">
                    NIVA
                </li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Liquid level controller for skimmer pools.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">
                    415,34 €
                </li>
                <li class="priceTotal">
                    3.322,72 €
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">
                    003
                </li>
                <li class="amount">
                    3 Pieces
                </li>
                <li class="name">
                    ALLPOOL
                </li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Multifunctional pool controller.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">
                    2.276,08 €
                </li>
                <li class="priceTotal">
                    6.828,24 €
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Table dummy data for testing printing -->
        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">001</li>
                <li class="amount">3 Pieces</li>
                <li class="name">DIGISOL</li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Solar heater controller with digital display.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">443,53 €</li>
                <li class="priceTotal">1.330,59 €</li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">
                    002
                </li>
                <li class="amount">
                    8 Pieces
                </li>
                <li class="name">
                    NIVA
                </li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Liquid level controller for skimmer pools.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">
                    415,34 €
                </li>
                <li class="priceTotal">
                    3.322,72 €
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">
                    003
                </li>
                <li class="amount">
                    3 Pieces
                </li>
                <li class="name">
                    ALLPOOL
                </li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Multifunctional pool controller.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">
                    2.276,08 €
                </li>
                <li class="priceTotal">
                    6.828,24 €
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Table dummy data for testing printing -->
        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">001</li>
                <li class="amount">3 Pieces</li>
                <li class="name">DIGISOL</li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Solar heater controller with digital display.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">443,53 €</li>
                <li class="priceTotal">1.330,59 €</li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">
                    002
                </li>
                <li class="amount">
                    8 Pieces
                </li>
                <li class="name">
                    NIVA
                </li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Liquid level controller for skimmer pools.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">
                    415,34 €
                </li>
                <li class="priceTotal">
                    3.322,72 €
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="posAmountName">
                <li class="pos">
                    003
                </li>
                <li class="amount">
                    3 Pieces
                </li>
                <li class="name">
                    ALLPOOL
                </li>
            </div>
            <li class="description">
                Multifunctional pool controller.
            </li>
            <div class="prices">
                <li class="priceSingle">
                    2.276,08 €
                </li>
                <li class="priceTotal">
                    6.828,24 €
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- There is more than a table at this page -->
        <p>
            T<br>e<br>x<br>t<br>.<br>T<br>e<br>x<br>t<br>.<br>T<br>e<br>x<br>t<br>.<br>T<br>e<br>x<br>t<br>.<br>T<br>e<br>x<br>t<br>.<br>T<br>e<br>x<br>t<br>.
        </p>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://crbug.com/1348526 might imply that using `<thead>` instead of `display: table-header-group` might work for you

Comment: Alternatively, try `@media print { .headFull { break-inside:avoid; } }` with the appropriate line breaks

Comment: @  dgrogan: Unfortunately `<thead>` can't not be used because: The `<thead>` tag must be used in the following context: As a child of a `<table>` element, after any `<caption>` and `<colgroup>` elements, and before any `<tbody>`, `<tfoot>`, and `<tr>` elements. See: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp

Comment: @ dgrogan: Wow, you're awesome! Although completely illogical, `break-inside: avoid;` solves the problem for prints using Chrome and Edge. This css instruction does not have to be in the `@media print`, it doesn't bother if it also applies to the screen. Thank you very much, I would never have thought of solving the problem (apparently a bug in Chrome and Edge) with `break-inside`. If you want to write another answer, I will accept it. Then this solution will be easier for others to find.

Comment: Questions to the voter: (1) If my question has no research effort and it is so clear: Why you didn't answer it? (2) Why is it not useful? (3) If this question is unclear for you, why you don't ask, what you don't understand, that I can make it clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements with `display: table-header-group` or `display: table-footer-group` will only be repeated across printed pages if they have some variants of [`break-inside: avoid`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-break-3/#propdef-break-inside) specified. This is called for by the [css tables spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-tables-3/#repeated-headers).

`<thead>` and `<tfoot>` elements have this property added by [Chrome's UA stylesheet](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/blink/renderer/core/html/resources/html.css;drc=873d63e71a9a041ae2c34bc7e71ccba986626b67;l=1511), so if you use those elements you don't have to specify any break-inside.